# undefined method `name' for ["Company Team Meeting", 25]:Array Rails options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I am working on the rails 5 application. I need to display dropdown of project.

I have @projects on controller and its values are
`[["Company Team Meeting", 25], ["BuildEffective", 1], ["VCF ", 86], ["StomerijCollectief", 114], ["StomerijCollectief - Enhancement", 130], ["Stomerij Mobile App", 135], ["Blog Writing", 138], ["Stomerij Design Enhancements", 139]]`

On view side I am using following code

`<%= f.options_for_select(@projects.map {|p| [p.name, p.id]})%>`

this gives me following error

`` undefined method `name' for ["Company Team Meeting", 25]:Array ``

Please help me

Please note: I am not in the projects controller

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an array of pairs you can just pass it straight to `options_for_select`:

```
<%= options_for_select(@projects) %>
```

But if you have a collection of records instead (instead of two plucked columns or wherever this data comes from) with you can use the [`collection_select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) helper instead of manually building the option tags and select tag.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:project_id, Project.all, :id, :name) %>
# or
<%= f.collection_select(:project_ids, Project.all, :id, :name, multiple: true) %>
```

Comment: It gave me 

undefined method `options_for_select' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x00007fd488334e10>

Comment: Ah, I see what wrong. `options_for_select` is a bare-bones helper and is not delegated by the form builder like most of the form helpers. Call it without `f.` on the view context (the implicit self in your views).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<%= f.options_for_select(@projects, object.id) %>`.
object_id will auto populate dropdown on edit.

Answer (score 0):

your `@projects` object is an Array type and so it don't have attributes like name and id.

you can place it like `<%= f.select :projects, options_for_select(@projects) %>`